# Customization beyond just the app drawer and home screen?

Tags: 7.1-nougat, customization, nova-launcher, motorola-moto-e4

I have a Motorola E4 running Nougat, and I was wondering if there was a way to customize the colors (and fonts if possible) used in the GUI menus? I have Nova launcher installed, and while it is nice to be able to tweak the app drawer and Home screen, it can't do much more than that AFAIK. Thanks.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=projekt.substratum

Comment: Okay, it appears root and/or custom ROM is required. That's more low level hacking than I want to do.